# docfx Shared Content between Markdown Files

Tags: docfx

In DocFX, I have a block of content which i need to put on all (or most) markdown files. Is there a way to merge or pull the contents of another `md` file in to the current file? Basically i am trying not to repeat myself and looking for some sort of sharing mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [file inclusion](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/spec/docfx_flavored_markdown.html?tabs=tabid-1%2Ctabid-a#file-inclusion) which is part of the DocFX flavored markdown (DFM).

> DFM adds syntax to include other file parts into current file, the
>   included file will also be considered as in DFM syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much! I almost started to write my own small merge tool for this. I do have a question though. In `[!include[<title>](<filepath>)]
`, i don't quite understand what the `title` is for. Where is that displayed?

Comment: It is not displayed anywhere in the resulting site, but may be used in build-time messages